# Angular leafeat json file input

Tags: angular, leaflet

I have taken this example and trying to create the same

https://codesandbox.io/s/ngx-leaflet-geojson-country-border-wlyw4?file=/src/app/app.module.ts

The problem I face is is a javascript error 'Invalid GeoJSON object' when I try and load the json file on line 79. When I do this in my code, one country is highlighted and works. How can I get the file to work?

```
    let geojson = L.geoJSON(this.geojsonFeature, {
      style: style,
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);

   geojsonFeature = {type: 'Feature' as const,
   properties: {
    "scalerank": 1,
    "featurecla": "Admin-0 country",
  "labelrank": 6,
  "sovereignt": "Albania",
  "sov_a3": "ALB",
  "adm0_dif": 0,
  "level": 2,
  "type": "Sovereign country",
  "admin": "Albania",
  "adm0_a3": "ALB",
  "geou_dif": 0,
  "geounit": "Albania",
  "gu_a3": "ALB",
  "su_dif": 0,
  "subunit": "Albania",
  "su_a3": "ALB",
  "brk_diff": 0,
  "name": "Albania",
  "name_long": "Albania",
  "brk_a3": "ALB",
  "brk_name": "Albania",
  "brk_group": null,
  "abbrev": "Alb.",
  "postal": "AL",
  "formal_en": "Republic of Albania",
  "formal_fr": null,
  "note_adm0": null,
  "note_brk": null,
  "name_sort": "Albania",
  "name_alt": null,
  "mapcolor7": 1,
  "mapcolor8": 4,
  "mapcolor9": 1,
  "mapcolor13": 6,
  "pop_est": 3639453,
  "gdp_md_est": 21810,
  "pop_year": -99,
  "lastcensus": 2001,
  "gdp_year": -99,
  "economy": "6. Developing region",
  "income_grp": "4. Lower middle income",
  "wikipedia": -99,
  "fips_10": null,
  "iso_a2": "AL",
  "iso_a3": "ALB",
  "iso_n3": "008",
  "un_a3": "008",
  "wb_a2": "AL",
  "wb_a3": "ALB",
  "woe_id": -99,
  "adm0_a3_is": "ALB",
  "adm0_a3_us": "ALB",
  "adm0_a3_un": -99,
  "adm0_a3_wb": -99,
  "continent": "Europe",
  "region_un": "Europe",
  "subregion": "Southern Europe",
  "region_wb": "Europe & Central Asia",
  "name_len": 7,
  "long_len": 7,
  "abbrev_len": 4,
  "tiny": -99,
  "homepart": 1
},
geometry: {
  type: 'Polygon',
  coordinates: [
    [
      [20.59024743010491, 41.855404161133606],
      [20.463175083099202, 41.51508901627534],
      [20.605181919037364, 41.086226304685226],
      [21.0200403174764, 40.84272695572588],
      [20.999989861747224, 40.58000397395398],
      [20.674996779063633, 40.43499990494303],
      [20.615000441172754, 40.11000682225938],
      [20.15001590341052, 39.62499766698397],
      [19.980000441170148, 39.69499339452341],
      [19.960001661873207, 39.91500580500605],
      [19.406081984136733, 40.250773423822466],
      [19.319058872157143, 40.72723012955356],
      [19.40354983895429, 41.40956574153546],
      [19.540027296637106, 41.71998607031276],
      [19.37176883309496, 41.877547512370654],
      [19.304486118250793, 42.19574514420782],
      [19.73805138517963, 42.68824738216557],
      [19.801613396898688, 42.50009349219084],
      [20.0707, 42.58863],
      [20.283754510181893, 42.32025950781508],
      [20.52295, 42.21787],
      [20.59024743010491, 41.855404161133606]
    ]
  ]
}
};
```

Comment: This does not look normal `type: 'Feature' as const`. Try to remove as const

Comment: removing the const works.... but why doesn't the file work

Comment: What do you mean why doesn't the file work, which file? your geojson is not valid if you use `as const`. Right now you are using a variable. Do you want to store it in a file like on the demo?

Comment: I tried the file exactly like the demo. But it says 'Invalid GeoJSON object'. I have no const in the file

Comment: Could you make a demo to reproduce the error you are getting?

Comment: I just created a demo https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-rubin-p3nr1?file=/src/app/app.component.html and that just works.... completely lost because I get a javascript error on my machine

Comment: That is weird indeed. I will try to download it and run it locally.

Comment: Thanks. The only difference is that I have put "resolveJsonModule": true in my tsconfig.json

Comment: What happens if you set it to false?

Comment: Tried but then I get this compiler error - 'Cannot find module './countries.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension.'